# Solving partial defferential equations

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, problem-solving

I Couldn't understand what to do with Integration of partial differential kinds equation till now. I wonder if there is a way to find a solution to below equation:

$\partial_{t}(e^{|k|^{a} }p(k,t)) = -c(t) *b* k[e^{t(|k|^{a}-|k+2 \pi/l|^{a})} +e^{t(|k|^{a}-|k-2 \pi/l|^{a})}+ 0.5(e^{t(|k|^{a}-|k+4 \pi/l|^{a})} + e^{t(|k|^{a}-|k+4 \pi/l|^{a})})]$

$c(t)= \frac{1}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-t|k|^{a}}dk}$
b is an imaginary constant.
I will be appreciated if someone knows the answer to this equation and help me. I have been thinking about it for 2 days and after a lot of searches, but I still don't really know what to do.

Comment: In$c(t)$, what is the integral with respect to?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the last exponent.

Comment: @vidyarthi it is respect to k

Comment: @TPP What do you mean?

Comment: The two exponents are the same.